# Xcode Instruments Leak calls free

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, free, instruments

I constantly find "leaks" using Xcode instruments (8.2) where `free` is the last call on the object/memory. If `free` is being called successfully then why would instruments be reporting this as a leak? Is this really a leak or a bug in instruments?

Here is one example

[image]

[image]

[image]

For example, this small segment of code seems to cause instruments to report leaks like these.

```
class RDTranslateComponentView: RDMessageCellComponentView {

    let textView: RDTextMessageCellComponentView
    let button: UIButton

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.textView = RDTextMessageCellComponentView()
        self.button = UIButton(type: .custom)

        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupView() {
        self.textView.label.font = UIFont.proximaSemiBold(withSize: 14)
        self.textView.label.textColor = UIColor.remindBrand()
        self.textView.bubble.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.addSubviews([ self.textView, self.button ])

        self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressedButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func pressedButton(_ sender: UIButton?) {
        /// Code that calls into a delegate
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return self.textView.sizeThatFits(size)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.textView.frame = self.bounds
        self.button.frame = self.bounds
    }
}

class RDMessageCellComponentView: UIView {
    /// The inside of this is just a bag of constants. Doesn't even touch anything View related so I'm omitting.
}
```

Here's a stack trace from my code in association to a leak. Keep in mind this isn't the only place this happens. This case props up often though and seems to be exclusive to code that has `UILabel` instantiated inside the `init` method of a subview that is added as a subview to another view.

[image]

Comment: The application is pretty complex and the stack trace is pretty deep, but this particular case seems to exclusively show up when initializing UILabels in subviews of a subview in swift. I found another photo that has a stack trace of where the code is initialized and I'll post it with the code. Keep in mind that this happens in other places in the application too with slightly varying stack traces. I'll see if I can reproduce a small scale test of this. It also doesn't show up in the memory graph debugger which is why I'm curious if this is just a bug in instruments with how it counts leaks.

Comment: @matt 
Ok, added some code. Not sure if that triggers the same issue outside of the scope of my application, will need to dive deeper to tease out the minimum requirements. Have you seen anything like this before? Where `free` is called but it registers as a leak?

Comment: What language is this? Objective-C?